# Why are Optional's or and flatMap methods' supplier type parameters wildcards?

Tags: java, option-type, java-9, supplier

The [`Optional.or`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#or(java.util.function.Supplier)) method was added in Java 9. This is the method signature

```
public Optional<T> or​(Supplier<? extends Optional<? extends T>> supplier)
```

Why is the type parameter of the `Supplier` taking `? extends Optional` rather than just `Optional`, since `Optional` is a *final* class?

The same is true for the `Optional.flatMap` method. This is a change from Java 8.

In Java 8, it was `Function<? super T, Optional<U>> mapper` whereas it was changed to `Function<? super T,​? extends Optional<? extends U>>` in Java 9.

Comment: Kinda seems like they're positioning it to not be a `final` class in future version?

Comment: @nbrooks It is because of the nested generics (and yes.. partly to due with the future changes)

Comment: My understanding of how this works is that, if a type argument is not for a wildcard type, the match must always be invariant. If you want to allow a subtype anywhere within the generic parameters of a type, then you need to use a wildcard type (or a new type variable) out to the outermost generic declaration. I *think* this is implied by section 18.2.3, "Subtyping Constraints", of the "Type Inference" chapter of the Java Language Specification. But that chapter is hard for me to wrap my brain around and I'm not confident enough in my understanding to write an answer spelling it out exactly.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I found the reasoning behind this from Stuart Marks himself

http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/core-libs-dev/2016-October/044026.html

This has to do with nested generics (`Optional` is nested within `Function`).
From the mail thread

> ```
>  Function<..., Optional<StringBuilder>>
> ```
>
> is not a subtype of
>
> ```
>  Function<..., Optional<? extends CharSequence>>
> ```
>
> To get around this, we have to add the outer wildcard as well, so that
>
> ```
>  Function<..., Optional<StringBuilder>>
> ```
>
> is a subtype of
>
> ```
>  Function<..., ? extends Optional<? extends CharSequence>>
> ```

Comment: +1. For me, the really mind-boggling thing here was why the easier "additional-type-parameter approach" `<V, U extends V> Optional<V> flatMap(Function<? super T, Optional<U>> mapper)` would *not* work in all circumstances.

Answer (score 11):

FWIW, a similar [issue](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8170946) with covariant arguments still exists in [Stream.iterate](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#iterate(T,java.util.function.UnaryOperator)) and [Stream.iterate](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#iterate(T,java.util.function.Predicate,java.util.function.UnaryOperator)) in Java 11. The current method signatures are

```
static <T> Stream<T> iterate(T seed, Predicate<? super T> hasNext, UnaryOperator<T> next)
static <T> Stream<T> iterate(T seed, UnaryOperator<T> f)
```

These signatures do not allow for some combinations of seeds and `UnaryOperator`s that are sound from a type perspective, e.g. the following doesn't compile:

```
UnaryOperator<String> op = s -> s; 
Stream<CharSequence> scs = iterate("", op); // error
```

The proposed solution is to change the method signatures to

```
static <T, S extends T> Stream<T> iterate(S seed, Predicate<? super S> hasNext, UnaryOperator<S> next)
static <T, S extends T> Stream<T> iterate(S seed, UnaryOperator<S> f)
```

So, in contrast to [Optional.or](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#or(java.util.function.Supplier)) and [Optional.flatMap](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#flatMap(java.util.function.Function))  this is a case where the "additional-type-parameter approach" actually works.

Answer (score 9):

Yeah... it is said that *wildcard with an extends-bound (upper bound) makes the type covariant*, which means that for example `List<Apple>` is an actual subtype of `List<? extends Fruit>` (considering that `Apple` extends `Fruit`); this is also called *covariance*.

Or in the examples that you have shown, it means that `Optional<StringBuilder>` is a subtype of `Optional<? extends Optional<? extends CharSequence>>`, so you could for example do:

```
List<Optional<String>> left = new ArrayList<>();
List<? extends Optional<? extends CharSequence>> right = new ArrayList<>();

right = left; // will compile
```

or assign a `Function` to the other